# iOS16. How to disable NavigationLink animation?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-animation

Is it possible to disable NavigationLink transition animation in SwiftUI?
To be more precisely. I want to disable it only for a few links/views. Not the whole app

Answer (score 0):

use : .animation(.none)

eg: `NavigationLink(destination: PdfView(isDepartures:false, ECFolioViewModel: FolioViewModel, isFromEasyCheckout: true),isActive:$FolioViewModel.isSuccess,label: { EmptyView()} ).animation(.none)`